# Recursive Hierarchy Ranking

Tags: sql, ms-access, data-mining, graph-theory

I have no idea if I wrote that correctly.  I want to start learning higher end data mining techniques and I'm currently using SQL server and Access 2016.

I have a system that tracks ID cards.  Each ID is tagged to one particular level of a security hierarchy, which has many branches.

For example

```
Root
-Maintenance
 - Management
  - Supervisory
  - Manager
  - Executive
 - Vendors
  - Secure
  - Per Diem
 - Inside Trades
```

There are many other departments like Maintenance, some simple, some with much more convoluted, hierarchies.

Each ID card is tagged to a level so in the Maintenance example, - Per Diem:Vendors:Maintenance:Root.  Others may be just tagged to Vendors, Some to general Maintenance itself (No one has root, thank god).

So lets say I have 20 ID Cards selected, these are available personnel I can task to a job but since they have different area's of security I want to find a commonalities they can all work on together as a 20 person group or whatever other groupings I can make.

So the intended output would be

```
CommonMatch = - Per Diem
CardID = 1
CardID = 3

CommonMatch = Vendors
CardID = 1
CardID = 3
CardID = 20
```

So in the example above, while I could have 2 people working on -Per Diem work, because that is their lowest common security similarity, there is also card holder #20 who has rights to the predecessor group (Vendors), that 1 and 3 share, so I could have three of them work at that level.

I'm not looking for anyone to do the work for me (Although examples always welcome), more to point me in the right direction on what I should be studying, what I'm trying to do is called, etc.  I know CTE's are a way to go but that seems like only a tool in a much bigger process that needs to be done.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not so much a graph-theory or data-mining problem but rather a data-structure problem and one that has almost solved itself.

The objective is to be able to partition the set of card IDs into disjoint subsets given a security clearance level.

So, the main idea here would be to layout the hierarchy tree and then assign each card ID to the path implied by its security level clearance. For this purpose, each node of the hierarchy tree now becomes a container of card IDs (e.g. each node of the hierarchy tree holds a) its own name (as unique identification) b) pointers to other nodes c) a list of card IDs assigned to its "name".)

Then, retrieving the set of cards with clearance **UP TO** a specific security level is simply a case of traversing the tree **from** that specific level downwards until the tree's leafs, all along collecting the card IDs from the node containers as they are encountered.

Suppose that we have access tree:

```
A
+-B
+-C
D
+-E
```

And card ID assignments:

```
B:[1,2,3]
C:[4,8]
E:[10,12]
```

At the moment, B,C,E only make sense as tags, there is no structural information associated with them. We therefore need to first "build" the tree. The following example uses [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) but the same thing can be achieved with a multitude of ways:

```
import networkx
G = networkx.DiGraph() #Establish a directed graph
G.add_edge("A","B")
G.add_edge("A","C")
G.add_edge("A","D")
G.add_edge("D","E")
```

Now, assign the card IDs to the node containers (in Networkx, nodes can be any valid Python object so I am going to go with a very simple list)

```
G.node["B"]=[1,2,3]
G.node["C"]=[4,8]
G.node["E"]=[10,12]
```

So, now, to get everybody working under "A" (the root of the tree), you can traverse the tree from that level downwards either via [Depth First Search (DFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [Breadth First Search (BFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and collect the card IDs from the containers. I am going to use DFS here, purely because Networkx has [a function that returns the visited nodes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_preorder_nodes.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_preorder_nodes) depending on visiting order, directly.

```
#dfs_preorder_nodes returns a generator, this is an efficient way of iterating very large collections in Python but I am casting it to a "list" here, so that we get the actual list of nodes back.
vis_nodes = list(networkx.dfs_preorder_nodes(G,"A")); #Start from node "A" and DFS downwards
cardIDs = []
#I could do the following with a one-line reduce but it might be clearer this way
for aNodeID in vis_nodes:
    if G.node[aNodeID]:
        cardIDs.extend(G.node[aNodeID])
```

In the end of the above iteration, cardIDs will contain all card IDs from branch "A" downwards in one convenient list.

Of course, this example is ultra simple, but since we are talking about trees, the tree can be as large as you like and you are still traversing it in the same way requiring only a single point of entry (the top level branch).

Finally, just as a note, the fact that you are using Access as your backend is not necessarily an impediment but relational databases [do not handle graph type data with great ease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#In_logic_and_computational_complexity). You might get away easily for something like a simple tree (like what you have here for example), but the hassle of supporting this probably justifies undertaking this process outside of the database (e.g, use the database just for retrieving the data and carry out the graph type data processing in a different environment. Doing a DFS on SQL is the sort of hassle I am referring to above.)

Hope this helps.